Lua - "malformed number near"
I have the following Lua script and it works fine until I add two decimal points. It errors with "malformed number near '10.7.5'"
if event.user_tag2 == "Team1" then
    event.sid = 10.1
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team2" then
    event.sid = 10.4
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team3" then
    event.sid = 10.6
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team4" then
    event.sid = 10.7
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team5" then
    event.sid = 10.7.5
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team6" then
    event.sid = 10.3
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team7" then
    event.sid = 10.2
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team8" then
    event.sid = 10.5
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team9" then
    event.sid = 10.9
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team10" then
    event.sid = 11.2
elseif event.user_tag2 == "Team11" then
    event.sid = 10.8
else
    event.sid = 10.4
end

return event

Does anyone have any ideas why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

a number can't have two decimals. I would suggest to use a string instead then. So event.sid = "10.7.5" (and of course for all other cases too, to keep it all the same type)

Thank you, I'll amend it and mark as solution

Also, use a table instead of a chain of ifs.

The error message is clear: 10.7.5 is not a valid number. Use strings instead. Moreover, you can replace a chain of ifs with a table, as in the code below.
t={
    ["Team1"] = "10.1",
    ["Team2"] = "10.4",
    ["Team3"] = "10.6",
    ["Team4"] = "10.7",
    ["Team5"] = "10.7.5",
    ["Team6"] = "10.3",
    ["Team7"] = "10.2",
    ["Team8"] = "10.5",
    ["Team9"] = "10.9",
    ["Team10"] = "11.2",
    ["Team11"] = "10.8",
}
event.sid = t[event.user_tag2] or "10.4"

